# How to mix Qt3D and default QtQuick.Controls?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt-quick, qt3d

I have an `Entity` with 3d content (not editable in Qt Creator designer tab) and an `ApplicationWindow` (which I want to be editable in Creator design tab) Ho to ember a Qt3d `Entity` into `ApplicationWindow` keeping `ApplicationWindow` editable in designer (as a green box for example)?

Comment: Use `Scene3D` component maybe? I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you are having trouble with any component (not just Qt3D) in the designer, you should consider splitting your contents into multiple files.

Add a separate MyUi.qml file for your UI and work on that in the designer, then use this file side-by-side with your 3D scene in the ApplicationWindow in the main.qml file. For example:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    MyUi {
        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            top: parent.top
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }
        width: parent.width / 2
    }
    Scene3D {
        anchors {
            right: parent.right
            top: parent.top
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }
        width: parent.width / 2
        MyRootEntity {
        }
    }
}
```